# Can't get PowerApps to import Data from SharePoint List if I use Look-up

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

First to give you a bit of context. I am trying to find a solution for the following scenario:

- Having to send meeting invites with dates, where people should choose just one and once a selection get's 10 submissions, it becomes grayed out.

I tried making a PowerApp on top of two SharePoint Lists, but I can't import if there are two columns linked between each other (to make the count). I tried to make the count directly in PA, but then I can't use the filter since it's a dynamic value.

Any help with the Filter or Importing that data from SharePoint Online would be appreciated.